# Devise_token_auth conflicts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-5, devise-token-auth

Made a new API in rails 5 using default --api tag and installed devise_token_auth gem using command
`rails generate devise_token_auth:install User auth` . On doing `rake:db:migrate`, I get this error `undefined method 'devise' for User (call 'User.connection' to establish a connection)` which is weird because devise_token_auth is built on top of devise..

So, commenting out routes throws error to user.rb file containing

`devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,:omniauthable
  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::User`

After commenting those lines out it throws error to application controller containing: 
`include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::SetUserByToken`
After commenting out this line, I get the devise:orm error.

Also tried adding devise to gemfile and installing devise for users, which failed too, throwing this error again `undefined method 'devise' for User (call 'User.connection' to establish a connection)`

Expected Migrations to go through,

Getting Devise errors

What should be done to resolve this?

PS- This was a third API I'm making using Devise_token_auth gem, didn't face this issue earlier

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a devise Issue, ActiveRecord ORM was hard coded inside of the gem before which has been changed now. This can be resolved by creating and adding the devise initializer as mentioned in the below documentation.

https://devise-token-auth.gitbook.io/devise-token-auth/config/initialization

There is also another way of fixing this, by adding the following in your user.rb model file.

```
extend Devise::Models
```

There is also an open issue in devise_token_auth

https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/issues/1276

Where you can follow up regarding this issue / Add in your thoughts for resolving this.

Answer (score 2):

Did you do the following steps -

Include gem in the `gemfile`-

`gem 'devise_token_auth'`

run generator:

`rails generate devise_token_auth:install User auth`

check if below line is added in `User` model:

`include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::User`

check if below line is added in `Application controller`:

`include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::SetUserByToken`

check if below line is added in `routes.rb`:

`mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth'`

add `extend Devise::Models` in User model

run `rake db:migrate`

Can you try removing the devise ,devise_token_auth gem and try these steps?
Let me know if any error pops up.

Comment: I did exactly the same already!! And tried it on a new App :-
Error on rake db:migrate :- `NoMethodError: undefined method `devise' for User (call 'User.connection' to establish a connection):Class`

Comment: @AmanRelan can you add `extend Devise::Models` in the User model and check the same?

Comment: That's what worked! thanks to you too for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I got this error and this was a fix for me.

1) Add 'devise_token_auth' gem in the Gemfile.

2) run rails g devise:install

3) run rails generate devise_token_auth:install User auth

4) run rails db:migrate

Comment: This fixed the issue right on this
pull: https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/pull/1307