# Devise Token Auth installation: default routing settings causing error

Tags: devise-token-auth

From a clean `create-repack-app` install. I add the following to my `Gemfile` then run `bundle`:

```
gem 'devise_token_auth'
```

Then I run:

```
rake db:create
rails g devise_token_auth:install
rake db:migrate
```

Databases (dev and test) are created and ruby files generated (including an addition to the `config/routes.rb` file). Trying any `rake` or `rails` command does the following right now:

```
rake routes
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `devise' for User (call 'User.connection' to establish a connection):Class
```

Commenting out the following in the `config/routes.rb` file:

```
mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth'
```

Removes this error. The code added to the `User` model doesn't contribute to this error. Do I need to run `rails g devise:install` also? The documentation doesn't mention anything extra. So I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Add below code to the **User** model

```
extend Devise::Models
```

My User model looks like this.

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend Devise::Models
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable, :trackable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::User
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer from another post: [Devise_token_auth conflicts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55626625/devise-token-auth-conflicts)

Adding the following Devise initializer:

**config/devise.rb**:

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  # The e-mail address that mail will appear to be sent from
  # If absent, mail is sent from "please-change-me-at-config-initializers-devise@example.com"
  config.mailer_sender = "support@myapp.com"

  # ==> ORM configuration
  # Load and configure the ORM. Supports :active_record (default) and
  # :mongoid (bson_ext recommended) by default. Other ORMs may be
  # available as additional gems.
  require 'devise/orm/active_record'

  # If using rails-api, you may want to tell devise to not use ActionDispatch::Flash
  # middleware b/c rails-api does not include it.
  # See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19600905/806956
  config.navigational_formats = [:json]
end
```

Fixed the problem.